# Sum of factorials and perfect squares

Tags: summation, factorial, integers

Is there a formula that explicits which $n$ makes the following a perfect square?

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i! = a^{2}, \quad a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

$$0^2 \equiv 0\pmod{10}$$
$$(\pm 1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod{10}$$
$$(\pm 2)^2 \equiv 4\pmod{10}$$
$$(\pm 3)^2 \equiv 9\pmod{10}$$
$$(\pm 4)^2 \equiv 6\pmod{10}$$

Find the unit digit of 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i! $$

for $n\ge4$.

Hint:

> $5!$ is a multiple of $10$.

Solution for all possible $n$:

> $n$ is either $1$ or $3$.